# Concatenate Host of a URL with other items in ItemTemplate as Anchor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET gridview control with a custom column that is an anchor tag and I'm having some issues with setting the URL.

Based on what I've constructed below, I would expect the that the HREF would come through as "myhost.local/Orders/FileName.PDF", but what I'm seeing it come through as"myhost.local/current directory/current page/myhost.local/Orders/FileName.pdf".  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**The Gridview**

```
<asp:GridView ClientID="GV" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_Search_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" ID="gv_Search" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Disciplinary Orders" SortExpression="defendant_name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="<%# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host %>/Orders<%# Eval("FileName") %> " target="_blank">
                 <%# Eval("FullName") %> - <%# Eval("CaseNumber") %> - Get Disciplinary Status </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the correct URL by changing to an ASP HyperLink and using `String.Format()`

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink 
        runat="server" 
        id="link" 
        NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("{0}", "/Orders/" + Eval("FileName")) %>' 
        Target="_blank">
        <%# Eval("FullName") + " - " + Eval("CaseNumber") %> - Get Disciplinary Status
  </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```